# error when trying to toggle a cmd discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Well I`m using this code to delete links that I wrote in links.txt

```
with open('C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Discord Bot\\links.txt') as file:
    file = file.read().split()
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global anti_add
    flag = False
    for link in file:
        if link in message.content.lower():
            await message.delete()
            flag = True
    if not flag:
        await client.process_commands(message)
```

It works and everything is okay
then i tried to toggle that like this

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def anti_add(ctx):
    global anti_add
    if anti_add == 'off':
        anti_add = 'on'
        await ctx.send('Ads Detector has been Enabled.')
        return anti_add

    else:
        anti_add = 'off'
        await ctx.send('Ads Detector has been Disabled.')
        return anti_add 


with open('C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Discord Bot\\links.txt') as file:
    file = file.read().split()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global anti_add
    flag = False
    for link in file:
        if anti_add = 'on':
        if link in message.content.lower():
            await message.delete()
            flag = True
    if not flag:
        await client.process_commands(message)
```

But it gives me this error

**line 139  if anti_add = 'on'  SyntaxError: invalid syntax**

Comment: It should be `anti_add == on`, `==` tells the program to compare while `=` turns it into a variable. Also at the end of the if statement you should add a `:`. And you should add an indentation after the if statement

Comment: i tried `if anti_add == on : ` error changed to **line 141
    if link in message.content.lower():
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def anti_add(ctx):
    global anti_add
    if anti_add == 'off':
        anti_add = 'on'
        await ctx.send('Ads Detector has been Enabled.')
        return anti_add
    else:
        anti_add = 'off'
        await ctx.send('Ads Detector has been Disabled.')
        return anti_add 


with open('C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Discord Bot\\links.txt') as file:
    file = file.read().split()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global anti_add
    flag = False
    for link in file:
        if anti_add == 'on':
            if link in message.content.lower():
                await message.delete()
                flag = True
    if not flag:
        await client.process_commands(message)
```

There you go! The indents were incorrect and you did not add `==`.

Comment: this happen `line 141
    if link in message.content.lower():
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block`

Comment: @AwJ Edited the answer! Have a look :)